# Can we show that each element of the Sobolev space $H^k(D)$, with $D\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ being a bounded domain, has a continuous representative?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let

- $d\in\left\{2,3\right\}$
- $D\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be a bounded domain
- $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $D$
- $H^k(D)$ be the [Sobolev space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#The_case_p_.3D_2)

> Can we show that each element of $H^k(D)$ has a continuous representative?

For $d=1$ and $D=(a,b)$ with $0<a<b<\infty$, it's easy to show that $$f(x)=\underbrace{f(a)+\int_{(a,\;x)}f'\;{\rm d}\lambda}_{=:\;g(x)}\;\;\;\text{for }\lambda\text{-almost all }x\in D$$ for all $f\in H^1$ (where $f'$ is the weak derivative of $f$). By Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, $g\in C^0(D)$ and since two continuous functions which equal $\lambda$-almost everywhere are identical, we can uniquely identify $f$ with $g$.

---

However, what about $d=3$? I'm aware of the [Sobolev embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Sobolev_embedding_theorem) which states that $$H^k(D)\hookrightarrow C^{\ell}(\bar D)\;\;\;\text{for all }\ell\in\left[0,k-\frac d2\right)\;,\tag 1$$ i.e. we need to choose $k\ge 2$.

Now, the statement of $(1)$ for $k=2$ and $\ell=0$ is that there is a bounded, linear and injective function $\iota:H^2(D)\to C^0(\bar D)$ where $H^2(D)$ is equipped with the Sobolev norm and $C^0(\bar D)$ is equipped with the supremum norm. Thus, each $f\in H^2(D)$ can be uniquely identified with $\iota(f)\in C^0(\bar D)$.

> The question is: Is $\iota$ the inclusion map? That's the case in the situation with $d=1$ described above. But is it the case in the situation with $d=3$ too?

If not, I assume that the answer to the first highlighted question is "no".

Comment: It almost is. $\iota (f)$ can be defined precisely via averages or regularization, and equals the original function $f$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @UmbertoP. So, we've got the same relationship between $f$ and $\iota(f)$ as in the case for $d=1$?!

Comment: Not really. In case $d=1$ functions in $H^1$ are absolutely continuous. There isn't a simple analogue when $d \ge 2$

Comment: @UmbertoP. I've meant the case $d=1$ that I've described. In other words: I've meant that (in both cases) we can identify $f$ with a continuous function $g$ ($=\iota(f)$) **which is an element of the $L^2(D)$-equivalence class of $f$**. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, provided $k > \frac d2$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Sure. Can you recommend a detailed proof?

Comment: Sure. See PDE by Evans. The exact statement is Theorem 5 on page 283 (2010 edition).

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thanks for your help! When Evans is writing $u\in C^0(D)$, he's actually meaning that one representative of $u$ is in $C^0(D)$, right? I'm unsure which conditions we need to impose on $D$. He's only saying that $D$ needs to be a bounded domain with $C^1$ boundary, but I've read in *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order*, by *Gilbarg* and *Trudinger*, that we need even a Lipschitz boundary. So, what is correct?

Comment: Continuity is a local property, so having a representative in $C^0(D)$ requires no boundary conditions on $D$. If you want the representative to belong to $C^0(\overline D)$ then some regularity is required. Evans just presents a slightly more restrictive hypothesis than Gilbarg/Trudinger.

Comment: @UmbertoP. When we're dealing with $L^2(D)$, is there any other option than going over to $H^2(D)$, if we need continuous representatives?